# Enter "Enter key" in Appium Testing

Tags: android, selenium, automation, appium, android-testing

How to send/press **Enter** key from soft keyboard in Appium in Android Automation testing? 
I tried several options, but none of them are working - instead of pressing the key, they are clearing the text entered in text area. Below is the code (in JAVA Language):

```
String app_package_name = "abc.xyz.android";

DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Nexus_5X_API_23");
capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "6.0");
capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", app_package_name);
capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", app_package_name + ".activity.StartupActivity_");

String url = "http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub";
AndroidDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL(url), capabilities);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

By password = By.id(app_package_name_with_id + "et_password");
WebElement enterPassword = driver.findElement(password);
enterPassword.click();
driver.getKeyboard().sendKeys("12345");

driver.getKeyboard().sendKeys(Keys.ENTER); // THIS IS NOT WORKING.
driver.getKeyboard().sendKeys(Keys.RETURN); // THIS IS ALSO NOT WORKING.
driver.pressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.ENTER); // THIS IS ALSO NOT WORKING.
driver.pressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.KEYCODE_NUMPAD_ENTER); // SAME HERE.
enterPassword.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER); // SAME HERE.
```

Please if anyone can help me achieve it?

Answer (score 6):

you can try this, it will work with all devices

```
driver.executeScript("mobile:performEditorAction", ImmutableMap.of("action", "done"));
```

Comment: Only solution working in my case . Even , ImmutableMap can be replaced by normal Map . e,g.             
 Map<String,String> map = new  HashMap();
 map.put("action", "done");
 driver.executeScript("mobile:performEditorAction", map);

Answer (score 3):

Before using

```
((AndroidDriver)driver).pressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.ENTER);
```

Set the following desired capabilities

```
capabilities.setCapability("unicodeKeyboard", "true");                                     
capabilities.setCapability("resetKeyboard", "true");
```

Comment: pressKeyCode and AndroidKeyCode had been deprecated. Any other idea/solution?

Comment: ((AndroidDriver) driver).pressKey(new KeyEvent(AndroidKey.ENTER));  <-- Use this. If it still didn't work try adding an element.click before it to click and activate the element

Answer (score 2):

Send using keyevent
Either use:
`driver.press_keycode(66)`
or
use
`adb shell input keyevent 66`

Comment: It works on Java too. The method is driver.pressKeyCode(66).

Answer (score 2):

Try following code. It is working for me:

```
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import io.appium.java_client.android.nativekey.AndroidKey;
import io.appium.java_client.android.nativekey.KeyEvent;

((AndroidDriver<MobileElement>) driver).pressKey(new KeyEvent(AndroidKey.ENTER));
```

> Before using enter key, you must first click on text input field.

Answer (score 1):

API Docs: https://appium.github.io/java-client/constant-values.html#io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidKeyCode.ENTER

Enter code is **66**

Python

```
self.driver.press_keycode(66)
```

Java

```
((AndroidDriver<MobileElement>) driver).pressKey(new KeyEvent(AndroidKey.ENTER));
```

I tested on Android 9 with Youtube search.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem while automating amazon `((AndroidDriver)driver).pressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.ENTER);` alone didn't work for me. But It worked when i clicked in the search box first.

```
searchBox.click();
searchBox.sendKeys("Example Input");
((AndroidDriver) driver).pressKey(new KeyEvent(AndroidKey.ENTER));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this ..

element.sendKeys("some text");
driver.pressKey(new KeyEvent(AndroidKey.ENTER));

Answer (score 0):

You can use Robot class :-

```
     Robot robot;
    try {
        robot = new Robot();
         robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
         robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    } catch (AWTException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

It is not recommended if your test cases are going to execute in the background. Robot framework just going to enter irrespectively without asserting anything.

Or you can try below code :-

```
driver.pressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.KEYCODE_NUMPAD_ENTER );
```

Source :- (It have other ways also to press enter) :-

https://discuss.appium.io/t/how-to-click-enter-after-entering-some-text/3136/4

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Your both solutions are not working with me. And the link you provided there as well I commented before posting question here. But no luck.

Comment: Try to put some wait like thread.sleep(4000); first... I am saying this because robot should work .. it may press enter and release but may be your element was not ready

Comment: I see Robot doesn't work with Appium. It's not Selenium!

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

```
try {
    driver.hideKeyboard();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @akash and @LuckyLikey led me to this solution in JavaScript:

`return driver.waitForElementById(<elementId>).type(<text to type>).click().execute( "mobile: performEditorAction", { "action": "search" } );`

This allowed me to find a text field, input some text, and submit a search command (same as clicking the search icon in the keyboard). Of course, you have to replace `<elementId>` and `<text to type>` with the proper values. See http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/mobile-command/ for details on "mobile: performEditorAction".

Answer (score 0):

So you can send below specified letter:

sendKeys('\n') for press Enter

Reference more [sendKeys API](http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/element/actions/send-keys/index.html) in other programing languages

Answer (score 0):

you can use action class, it worked for me

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

So you can like this which has worked for me in some situations in the past and its real simple

for press Enter

```
sendKeys('\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a better solution instead of pressing ENTER button.

I wrote the following command:

```
driver.hideKeyboard();
```